# Valid use of Total Probability Law/Total Expectation Law (Discrete and Continous)

Tags: probability

Say we have r.vs $X$ (discrete), $Y$ (continuous), where $Y$ has some dependency on $X$.  Would this then be an accurate application of the TEL/TPL?

$$P(Y \leq y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(Y \leq y |X=k)*p_X(k)$$

I see it as since we are "summing" over a discrete variable, the expression should be a sum, and if the case was reversed with $X$ continuous and $Y$ discrete, it would be an integral over y instead.

Related question: My teacher uses the name TEL and TPL interchangeably when performing these calculations. Now TEL is of course $E(Y) = E(EY|X))$, and we can apply it when doing something like $P(A = x) = E(I_{A})$ (Where $I_{A}$ is the indicator of event $A$). Is it correct to say that this relation makes the two equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is fine, ... assuming of course that $X$ is a discrete random varuable *whose support is covered by the natural numbers*.

And you are also correct that the expectation form of probability make the LTP and LTE equivalent.   Technically; though we generally do not interchange the terms in practice.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\leq y) ~=~& \mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{Y\leq y})\\~=~& \mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{Y\leq y}\mid X)) \\ =~& \sum_{x\in\Bbb N} \mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{Y\leq y}\mid X=x)~p_X(x) \\=~& \sum_{x\in\Bbb N}\mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)~p_X(x)\end{align}$$

And the analogous statement would be:
$$\mathsf P(X\leq x)=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(X\leq x\mid Y=y)~f_Y(y)\operatorname d y$$

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, such conditions on X are of course necessary!